# JWT Async sign Token prints as undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I'm trying to do my first login with JWT but every time I try to sign in the login the token comes back as undefined and I think it skips the response as it shows it empty. I'm sure this should be node/js problem more than a JWT one but I cant seem to figure it out.

The code:

```js
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserStudent.findOne({
      registerNumber: req.body.registerNumber,
    });

    const jwt = await Login(req.body.password, user.password, user);

    console.log("wont print this and the json response comes back empty");
    res.status(200).json("Logged");
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

```js
login = async (password, hash, user) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function (err, result) {
      jwt.sign(
        user,
        "ultrasecretkey",
        { algorithm: "RS256" },
        function (err, token) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          console.log("This token shows undefined:", token);
          resolve(token);
        }
      );
    });
  });
};
```

I know the parameters are passed correctly to the login function

Update: While trying a different object instead of user it gives me this error:

```
    "message": {
        "library": "PEM routines",
        "function": "get_name",
        "reason": "no start line",
        "code": "ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE"
    }
```

Comment: What is `Login`? Did you mean `login` (JS is case sensitive)?

Comment: Please use your jwt key hard coded instead of `process.env.JWT_KEY` for better debugging.

Comment: Is user a string containing the username? JWT expects an object, not a string concerning to the docs. Additionally: you aren't using the result of the pw hash compare.

Comment: @MBPictures User is a json object, but then again I have tried it with the foo bar as presented in the documentation

Comment: @Phil Its Login as I'm defining : const Login = require('../services/login')

Comment: You're not handling errors particularly well. Where is the check for the `bcrypt.compare()` error? Why not log errors when they occur, eg `if (err) { console.error(err); return reject(err); }`

Comment: What happens if you use the sync call (without the callback but using the return of the function)?

Comment: @Phil should probably done it sooner I changed the object back to foobar and added logged the error in console and it returns this error:0909006C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick online demonstration:  https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3yhwngbq9

Basically your problem is that you are trying to use a private key/public key algorithm but you are not providing a private key.

If you want to sign using a simple password, you must change your algorithm to `HS256`, which is the default, by the way.  Your selection of `RS256` is what gives you a headache.